# Confluence rest API doesn't create page with new editor

Tags: api, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to create new content page from confluence REST api.

Any page created with REST API show up in old editor view. I have tried editor2 option instead of storage and also i tried with metadata([Example](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Creating-space-using-REST-API-creates-it-with-quot-old-quot/qaq-p/1275954)), but no luck.

Is there any solution by which i can create page in new editor (v2) from REST API of confluence.

Answer (score 1):

Found this example on [Atlassian.net](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Creating-space-using-REST-API-creates-it-with-quot-old-quot/qaq-p/1275954?tempId=eyJvaWRjX2NvbnNlbnRfbGFuZ3VhZ2VfdmVyc2lvbiI6IjIuMCIsIm9pZGNfY29uc2VudF9ncmFudGVkX2F0IjoxNjE2MTgxMTA0NTA4fQ%3D%3D#U1643258) and it works for me:

```
curl -u 'user:apitoken' -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  'https://hello.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content' \
  -d '{
  "type": "page",
  "title": "Page created via API",
  "space": {
    "key": "TEST"
  },
  "body": {
    "storage": {
      "value": "<h1>Test page</h1>",
      "representation": "storage"
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "properties": {
      "editor": {
        "value": "v2"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```